# PostgreSQL: Count the duration in hours between two timestamps and subtract hours from weekends

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I have been trying to create the following SQL query (PostgreSQL 12.14) for days, but I can't figure it out.

The query should calculate the duration in hours between two timestamps, but only count the hours that fall on workdays.

> Example:
>
> created_on = 27.04.2023 14:00:00
> NOW() = 02.05.2023 - 08:00:00
>
> The correct result should be 66 hours:
> 27.04 = 10h (from 14:00 to 00:00)
> 28.04 = 24h
> 29.04 = 0h (Saturday)
> 30.04 = 0h (Sunday)
> 01.05 = 24h
> 02.05 = 8h (from 00:00 to 08:00)

Thank you for your help
Michael

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly the following gives it. You are looking for the `sum` of hours over several intervals. Those intervals are defined as the between `start` timestamp and the end that day, between the beginning of the day for the  `end` and the actual time of that time on that day, and an interval of 24 hours for each day between the `start` and `end` dates; excluding the days Saturday and Sunday. (see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gkmMXRJVgP9QgezeL57yG8/0))

```
with each_day (start_dtm, end_dtm, act_dt) as 
     ( select start_dtm, end_dtm 
            , generate_series( date_trunc('day', start_dtm) 
                             , date_trunc('day', end_dtm )  
                             , interval '1 day'
                             ) act_dt
         from (select start_dtm, end_dtm from hours) h
     ) -- select * from each_day;
   , hours_per_day (start_dtm, end_dtm, act_dt, hrs) as 
     ( select each_day.*
            ,case when date_trunc('day', start_dtm) = act_dt  then act_dt+interval '1 day' - start_dtm
                  when date_trunc('day', end_dtm) = act_dt    then end_dtm - act_dt
                  else                                        make_interval (hours => 24) 
                end
         from each_day
        where extract(isodow from act_dt) < 6 
     )  -- select * from hours_per_day; 
select start_dtm, end_dtm, extract(hours from sum(hrs)) "Duration in Hours"
  from hours_per_day
 group by start_dtm, end_dtm
 order by date_trunc('day', start_dtm), end_dtm;
```

The query first creates 2 CTEs. the *each_day* CTE uses the  `generate series` function to expand the start and end dates with the dates between them, inclusively. The second CTE `hours_per_day` is the real workhorse. It determines whether the date is the first day or the last day of the period. For each it computes the appropriate interval (subtraction of timestamps gives the interval) for those days and, for intervening days creates and interval of 24 hours (1 day). In addition it discards Saturdays and Sundays. Finally, the main query computes the `sum` of the of those intervals and extracts the hours.